# Action upon a key press (Python)

Tags: python-2.7

I want to code the following in Python. When I press a key let's say the key "a", the program needs to write to a logfile that the subject for example answered "left".

Can you help me with this?

Thnx a lot!

Comment: Are you on Windows? Does it only need to detect keypresses when the Python window has focus? Use [`msvcrt.getch`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/msvcrt.html#msvcrt.getch). Do you need to detect keypresses in any window? Use [`win32api.GetKeyState`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I know that we shouldn't make assumptions, but I can't add comments yet to get a clarification. I am also quite confident that you want to write a game from the way you phrased the question (what with WASD and "A" being "left"). If this is not the case, please let me know and I'll delete this answer.

You could implement something very similar to what you want in "naked" Python, along these lines:

```
from sys import exit

def get_answer():
    while True:
        answer = raw_input("A to go left, D to go right, W to go up, S to do down, QUIT to exit")
        if answer == "QUIT" or "quit":
            exit("You have quit the game.")
        if answer == "A" or "a":
            #call function for going left
        if answer == "D" or "d":
            #call function for going right
        if answer == "W" or "w":
            #call function for going up
        if answer == "S" or "s":
            #call function for going down
        else:
            print "Please make sure that your answer is W, A, S, D or QUIT."

#(all the other functions go here)

done = False
#"Pseudo event loop"
while not done:
    #function that draws
    get_answer()
    #function for all the logic that happens after character moves; fight etc.
    #function that checks if game is finished and if it is, sets done to True
```

While you will never get something very dynamic created with this approach, it's still enough to finish a small fun game. The obvious downside here is that the "Pseudo event loop" will wait for user to finish the "get_answer()". I don't think that it's realistic to implement this in "naked" Python in a much better way.

If you wanted to create a game with actual graphics and where things will happen regardless of if user has any input or not (e.g. enemies walking by themselves), I would strongly recommend looking into a framework like PyGame (it's very well documented). Implementing an actual event loop in it is very simple, and it allows you to get the desired "action upon a key press" behavior.